# multiple images and buttons on a single jframe

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am designing a blackjack game in Java.

I am done with writing the logic for the game but having problems designing the GUI.

I have a function which generates random number every time a player wants to hits.

I have picked up an image of the  blackjack table and am thinking of displaying the images of the cards over it at specified locations. I also want a Hit and a Stand button, again over the blackjack table's image.

The piece of code I have displays the initial hand of the dealer and the player but the problem is that I am unable to think of a code to update the `Jframe` every time a new card is generated. Also the buttons are not showing. That is where i am looking for help. I am a beginner to using Jframes, Jpannels etc. This is what i have.

```
  public class Check extends Panel {
    BufferedImage img;
    BufferedImage img1;
    BufferedImage img2;
    BufferedImage img3;
    BufferedImage img4; 

public Check()
 {

try {
img = ImageIO.read(newFile("C:\\Users\\Abc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\blackjack\\src\\blackjack\\images\\table.jpg"));

} catch (IOException e) {
}

try {
int n,j;
    n=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4 - 1) + 1));
    j=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));



 img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Abc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\blackjack\\src\\blackjack\\images\\"+n+"-"+j+".gif"));

} catch (Exception e) {

}
try {
     int n,j;
    n=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4 - 1) + 1));
    j=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));

 img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Abc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\blackjack\\src\\blackjack\\images\\"+n+"-"+j+".gif"));
     } catch (Exception e) {

  }

try {
     int n,j;
    n=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4 - 1) + 1));
    j=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));

 img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Abc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\blackjack\\src\\blackjack\\images\\"+n+"-"+j+".gif"));

} catch (Exception e) {

}

try {

 img4 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Abc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\blackjack\\src\\blackjack\\images\\rear.gif"));
     } catch (Exception e) {

}


}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
g.drawImage( img, 0, 0, this);
g.drawImage(img1, 470, 475, this);
g.drawImage(img2, 510, 475, this);
g.drawImage(img3, 510, 125, this);
g.drawImage(img4, 470, 125, this);


 }

static public void main(String args[]) throws
Exception {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display image");
JButton b = new JButton("HIT");
b.setBounds(100,100,110,100);
b.setVisible(true);
Panel panel = new Check();
panel.add(b);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.setSize(1024,768);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Comment: The initial images are the originally dealt cards. Leave the others blank. Put an action listener on the button and inside the listener you read the new card into the next place for cards. Then make sure it repaints. Maybe this will give you some clues.

Comment: BTW. Blackjack does not randomly select a card for every one dealt. It takes X decks of cards with fixed values and orders them for selection. A deal consists of getting the next one already dealt. This keeps it from randomly selecting the 3 of clubs over and over and over.

Comment: Why `Panel` instead of `JPanel`?

Comment: I am able to display the button on the frame now but not at my desired location . Also how do i use the repaint function?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `super.repaint(g)` as the first statement of `paint` method to make the `Button` to visible on `Panel`:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
...
}
```

Comment: I am able to display the button on the frame.But how do i use the repaint function?